# How to remove a very large folder (~40GB) with lots of files efficiently in Linux

Tags: linux

I'd like to remove a folder with lots (millions) of files efficiently. When I issue `rm -rf folder/`, it takes hours, and I have to kill it. I'm wondering whether there is a magical way of doing this faster?

Another thing is when I want to get the size of the folder with `du -hs folder/`, it also takes a very, very long time. I was never patient to wait for it and killed it after several hours.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this question: [http://serverfault.com/questions/183821/rm-on-a-directory-with-millions-of-files](http://serverfault.com/questions/183821/rm-on-a-directory-with-millions-of-files)

Answer (score 4):

From [here](http://linuxnote.net/jianingy/en/linux/a-fast-way-to-remove-huge-number-of-files.html):

```
rsync -a --delete ./emptyDirectoty/ ./hugeDirectory/
```

Comment: One note about that table: Did they mix user and system time? The first row command has `elapsed 10.60 system 1.31` while the output says `elapsed 12.42 user 1.31 system 10.60`.

Comment: @ott--: Well spotted, I'm not sure what to make of that. The second row is even weirder `28.51, 14.46` vs `0.41, 14.46`.

Comment: I'd trust the output, the table needs the 3 colums `Elapsed` `System` and `User` with the correct values.

Comment: @ott--: I've sent the OP an email to see if he can clarify the results.